# Custom Post Type Root Template

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type for this project I'm working on. I've defined the URL slug to be 'vendors'.

So now when I browse to www.mysite.com/vendors, it shows all of my Custom Post Type posts.

I don't want the root slug to be a listing of all my posts.

Is there a way to have a custom template defined for the /vendors/ slug?

Comment: Hard to answer without more detail. I would suspect bad code in the template or a bad `pre_get_posts` filter.

Comment: Did you specify a custom `archive-vendors.php` template?

Comment: I can post my `register_post_type` code if it'll help. Basically the post type is working fine. I've populated it with a bunch of posts. But when I browse to just the root. mysite.com/vendors. I get a list of all my posts. Sort of like a custom `is_home()`. I'm looking to replace the post listing with my own template code - I just don't know the hook to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions:

1. Create `archive-vendors.php`, that displays whatever output you want (including static content or a secondary query, for example), and omitting the default loop (CPT archive index query).
2. Set `has_archive` to `false` in your `register_post_type()` call, then create a *static page* named **Vendors**, that you can use to display whatever content you want (including via a custom page template).

Comment: I created a `archive-vendors.php` to my theme folder, and set `has_archive` to `true`, yet I'm still getting a post listing like `is_home()`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I was playing around with option 1 and 2, and it looks like after I made my changes, I had to reset my permalinks again. I ended up going with option 2, since that will involve the least amount of work required. Thanks!